# Validate post sub item in AdonisJs

Tags: javascript, typescript, adonis.js

Validate post sub item in AdonisJs.

I can't validate a sub item of the post. I believe it is not found.

I need to validate "codigo" that is inside "nfe"

Request

```
{
  nfe: {
    codigo: '56456',
    motorista: 'NOME',
    contato: 'CONTATO',
    casa: true
  },
  fornecedor: 'ALIMENTOS',
  lab: 'sim',
}
```

Controller

```
await request.validate(NfeValidator)
```

Validator

```
public schema = schema.create({
    'nfe.codigo': schema.string({trim: true}, [rules.unique({table: 'nfes', column: 'codigo'})])
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A field was included in the root of the request post to be checked.